# How to install a newer version of MySQL workbench than is available in my distro's repos

Tags: apt, mysql, repository

I am trying to install a version of MySQL workbench that is NEWER than what is available to me through the regular debian repos.

I started by adding testing, unstable and experimental repos, but even they don't have the version I'm looking for (6.3.6).

So I tried following these instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html), I added the MySQL repo, ran `apt-get update` and am getting `Unable to locate package mysql-server-community`

I can, and have installed the `mysql-workbench` package, but the instructions explicitly state to use the `community` version.

The version I have installed now is `6.2.3`.

Also, my MySQL *server* version is `5.5.46` and I would rather not upgrade it as we are developing with that version.

So what gives?

I should point out that I am running debian 8 and am using the DEB section of the linked instructions.

Comment: I suppose you could download the source code of mysql-workbench on an official site, and **make/make install** it

Comment: I'd rather do it the clean way through apt.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mysql-workbench There is a package.  Also make sure you have the right sources on your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file Actually, it is 6.2.3, so I suppose you do want a newer version. Maybe apt does not have the sources yet

Comment: That is not the right package, i require version 6.3.6 as it fixes a specific bug I am encountering.

Comment: I noticed that during the "apt-get update", it says "IGN" next to all of the mysql sources I added. Could that be ingore?

Comment: I do not know what IGN means. Anyway,  mysql seemingly has some sort of reposistory, you could add that to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Answer (score 4):

It does not seem that Debian's APT reposistories have the newer version of MySQL. And since you want it maintained by APT, rather than install from source code, you can use MySQL's official reposistory. There is a deb package for APT installation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/), with short instructions

First, add the MySQL APT repository to your system's software repository list. Follow these steps:

> Go to the download page for the MySQL APT repository at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/.
>
> Select and download the release package for your platform.
>
> Install the downloaded release package with the following command, replacing version-specific-package-name with the name of the downloaded package (preceded by its path, if you are not running the command inside the folder where the package is):
>
> `shell> sudo dpkg -i /PATH/version-specific-package-name.deb`
>
> For example, for version w.x.y-z of the package, the command is:
>
> `shell> sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_w.x.y-z_all.deb`
>
> Note that the same package works on all supported Debian and Ubuntu platforms.
>
> During the installation of the package, you will be asked to choose the versions of the MySQL server and other components (for example, the MySQL Workbench) that you want to install. If you are not sure which version to choose, do not change the default options selected for you. You can also choose none if you do not want a particular component to be installed. After making the choices for all components, choose Apply to finish the configuration and installation of the release package.
>
> You can always change your choices for the versions later; see Selecting a Major Release Version for instructions.
>
> Update package information from the MySQL APT repository with the following command (this step is mandatory):

Then install normally using `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: I already followed those instructions to the T, and the package to install is "mysql-workbench-community" not the one you mentioned. Installing "mysql-workbench" won't install the newest version (won't fetch it from the mysql repo, but the debian repo)

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` is mandatory, according to the documentation. You also have an option to temporarily comment out all the Debian reposistories from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I ran sudo apt update, and when I look in the sources list, there are no mysql repos, however when i run the update, I can see mysql repo addresses whizzing by... I dont know whats going on...

Comment: Well then try temporarily comment out all the debian repos from the sources list

Comment: But there wont be any repos after that? Is that what you intend?

Comment: I suppose that Debian repos are the first to be searched, and since they contain it, they install from there. So I would do it **temporarily** to obstruct that in the case of prioritizing

Comment: Ok, i also added testing, unstable and experimental.. I suppose ill have to disable those as well?

Comment: I think you should try commenting all the debian repos, with unstable and experimental, and then uncomment it after the installation. Maybe if you had to repeat, you could make a shell script doing it for you as a workaround

Comment: Ok i removed ALL the repos except for mysql, and still it says package not found.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you found the solution or not. There are several options you could try out -

1. Upgrade from jessie to stretch and get 6.3.8+dfsg-1
2. File a wishlist bug saying you would like mysql-workbench to be backported to jessie. See https://itsfoss.com/bug-report-debian/ if you want to learn how to file a bug.
3. Use one of the options above.

The rest, as they say is upto you.

Answer (score 0):

First check the version of your OS, if it is: Ubuntu **20.04** then download Ubuntu Linux **20.04** (x86, 64-bit), DEB Package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

**Be careful with the version of OS and your downloaded Workbench version**

Then open a terminal and follow these commands:

1. cd Downloads (if the file is in the Download folder)
2. ls (copy the file name)
3. sudo apt install ./filename   (e.g. sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.22-1ubuntu**version no**_amd64.deb)

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 20.10 now. That's what has worked to me:

1. Download MySQL APT Repository from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ as mentioned by @john-k
2. `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb`, again, as John said.
3. `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench` - this did not work to me so you may skipp it too. I got the following error:

```
...
Package mysql-workbench is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-workbench-community

E: Package 'mysql-workbench' has no installation candidate
```

4. `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community` - this worked, weirdly. Got this notification back:

```
...
mysql-workbench-community is already the newest version (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk libcaf-openmpi-3 libcdio18 libcfitsio8
  libdns-export1109 libdvdread7 libevent-extra-2.1-7 libffi7:i386
  libgeos-3.8.0 libgfortran-9-dev libgrantlee-textdocument5 libgsoap-2.8.91
  libicu66:i386 libllvm10 libllvm10:i386 libmalcontent-0-0 libmozjs-68-0
  libmutter-6-0 libnettle7 libnettle7:i386 libpoppler97 libproj15 libqpdf26
  libsane libsrt1 libtepl-4-0 liburl-dispatcher1 libx264-155 libx265-179
  openmpi-bin openmpi-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

5. `sudo apt autoremove` - clean up has been recommended, so I did it
6. `sudo apt-get update` - resynchronize index files from their sources.
7. `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community` - this finally installed it.
8. `mysql-workbench --version` results to the following now:

```
Found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.19
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 8.0.23 CE build 365764
```

Answer (score -1):

For beginners who land here from google on Ubuntu and may not necessarily have a strict need to use `sudo apt-get mysql-workbench` but are more familiar with it than manually downloading packages… using `apt-get` is **not the only option!**

1. Simply uninstall the older version of `mysql-workbench` that comes with your distro (presumably you've done that and now realize the version is too old):

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench
   ```
2. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
   (don't bother registering).

   Download the package and double click the downloaded package, software center takes over.
3. Access it via finder to connect to your remote databases type "mysq".